# How do i get a specific data from responseBody on postman

Tags: json, postman

I'm trying to set an environment variable using the following:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);   
pm.environment.set("petId", data.id);
```

And this is what is in my response:

```
{
    "id": 9222999990497629102,
    "category": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "dog"
    },
    "name": "Brutus",
    "photoUrls": [
        "http://placeimg.com/640/480"
    ],
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "string"
        }
    ],
    "status": "available"
}
```

But somehow my environment looks like this:

```
"petId": "9222999990497629000"
```

I don't where from where I'm getting these last zeros on my variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
pm.environment.set("petId", JSON.parse(pm.response.text().replace(/"id":[\s]*([\d]+),/,'"id":"$1",')).id);
```

As the id is a big int greator than MAX_SAFE_Integer , the response will be rounded when parsed as JSON. It is a javascript behavior.

You can enclose it with double quotes. After that extract that id.

now if you want to convert id to number use BigInt

```
let id = JSON.parse(pm.response.text().replace(/"id":[\s]*([\d]+),/,'"id":"$1",')).id

id = BigInt(id)

console.log(id)
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt